# How to Nil a object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, null

How to assign nil to an object in Swift. I'm getting error if assigned directly.

[image]

Comment: try use Swift optional type

Comment: Only Optional variables can be assigned as nils. What's the type of lastRecordedLocation?

Comment: @Shai it a non optional CLLocation variable.

Comment: If it's not an optional, you can't assign nil to it :-)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[From Apple Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> **nil cannot be used with nonoptional constants and variables**. If a
> constant or variable in your code needs to work with the absence of a
> value under certain conditions, always declare it as an optional value
> of the appropriate type

also very importante to notice:

> **Swift’s nil is not the same as nil in Objective-C**. In Objective-C, nil
> is a pointer to a nonexistent object. In Swift, nil is not a
> pointer—it is the absence of a value of a certain type. Optionals of
> any type can be set to nil, not just object types

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 39):

Please check below:

```
var lastRecordedLocation: String?
lastRecordedLocation = nil
```

Comment: had to combine the two lines into 1 for it to work but this solved my problem

Answer (score 18):

To nil the object, it has to be declared with nil by **? mark**. This means that the value can (possibly) be a nil. So declare it as :

```
var lastRecordedLocation: String?
```

and then you can set it to nil

```
lastRecordedLocation = nil
```

Answer (score 7):

NOTE : If you define an optional variable without providing a default value, the variable is automatically set to nil for you:

```
var lastRecordedLocation: String?
// lastRecordedLocation is automatically set to nil
   or
lastRecordedLocation = nil
```

Answer (score 6):

That means your `lastRecordedLocation` object is not `Optional` type.
If you make lastRecordedLocation as Optional such as:

```
var lastRecordedLocation:String?
```

You can set nil to that object later.

Answer (score 2):

Only optional can be nil

`var lastRecordedLocation:CLLocation?` or this
`var lastRecordedLocation:CLLocation!`

Answer (score 2):

if you want nil the property , you need the **Optional** value for the **lastRecordedLocation**

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to empty a previously filled Data type variable

```
var jsonData = Data()
```

The variable had been used for JSON serialisation before but was taking up too much memory, so I just reinitialised it and the size becomes 0 bytes again.