# Assign nil to object in guard var statement

Tags: swift, generics

I have a code like this

```
class Test1<T> {

    func demo(_ obj0: Test1<T>?) {
        guard var obj1 = obj0 else { return }
        //    obj1 = nil // ERROR            

        // WORK AROUND
        var obj2 = obj0  
        obj2 = nil  // WORKS FINE
    }
}
```

As mentioned if assign nil to obj1, It shows error

```
// ERROR : Nil cannot be assigned to type 'Test'
```

But if i assign it another variable and assign nil it works fine.

I searched and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30613532/5589073

So what should i do alternative to this error?
I don't want 3 rd variable and assign nil

Comment: Why would you wish to assign `nil` to `obj1`? The whole point of the `guard` is to ensure that `obj0` wasn't `nil` and to create a non-optional variable (`obj1`) holding the non-nil value of `obj0`.

Comment: @rmaddy : i 'm working on deleting last node of a binary tree and the function is recursive. So In intermediate state i need object and when node get found in last i have to delete via assign nil like in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

`guard var obj1 = obj0` implies the type of `obj1` to be unwrapped type of `obj0` ie, type of `obj1` will be `Test1<T>` not `Test1<T>?`. So assigning a `nil` to it is not possible.

On the otherhand, swift compiler infers the type of `obj2` to be `Test1<T>?`. So it is possible to assign `nil` to it.

**Update**:

You can remove the guard statement and use `if` statement instead. Then assign `obj1` with `obj0`. The compiler will infer the type of `obj1` to be same as `obj0`

```
if obj0 == nil { return }
var obj1 = obj0
```

Answer (score 1):

`guard let` unwraps an optional value, which means it will turn an optional value into a non-optional one if the value is not nil. This is why you can't assign `nil` to `obj1`

If you want to keep the optionality of `obj0`, then don't unwrap it into `obj1`, just check for nil:

```
guard obj0 != nil else { return }
var obj1 = obj0
```

Alternatively, you could keep `obj0` and shadow it:

```
var obj0 = obj0
guard obj0 != nil else { return }
```